# Materilize js code that does email validation

Tags: javascript

The email validation mentioned on https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html says that there is a "validate" class made available by Materialize CSS file that the Materilize JS file picks up and does the actual validation.

I am trying to find the function that does the email validation (the fact that someone has entered abc@xyz and not just abc) in the [Materilize JS file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.js)

In the code block

> window.validate_field = function (object) {

I cant make out where it actually checks for @ part of entered text.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: row 4348 of the file, check for validate_field 

By the way they just control if the field is valid in html5, if it is a input type = email, they check if your email is valid or not with a pattern of the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented by supported browsers, and not through javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email

Then through JS you check for the pseudo class. (The :valid and :invalid CSS pseudo-classes are automatically applied as appropriate).

In materialize.js they check for the pseudo class and add their own classes:

```
...
if (object.is(':valid') && hasLength && len <= lenAttr || object.is(':valid') && !hasLength) {
  object.removeClass('invalid');
  object.addClass('valid');
} else {
...
```

Comment: can you please explain... `hasLength && len <= lenAttr`

Comment: That is additional validation if you have set a maximum length then it checks if that field has a length attribute.

Comment: Please remove `&& hasLength && len <= lenAttr` from your answer

Comment: That is code identical from materialJs, not code I wrote.

Comment: Ok...Sorry then +1 for explanation :-) have a great day